# Ошибка при импорте базы MySQL

Tags: mysql

При попытке залить в PHPMyAdmin базу на новый хостинг выдает ошибку:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‹' at line 12
```

Даже здесь не вставляются спецсимволы, которые есть в том выводе (вместо near '‹' должно быть near 'спецсимвол1‹спецсимвол2')

Как понимаю, дело в спецсимволах, которые содержатся в базе. Как их экранировать или обойти это ограничение, чтобы нормально залить базу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в формате сжатия загружаемого файла. По какой-то причине MySQL не захотел обрабатывать данные, сжатые в формате gzip, но при этом прекрасно все загрузил в формате zip (также все хорошо загружается в текстовом виде, sql).

В тексте имелись спецсимволы, которые, полагаю, некорректно обрабатывались при сжатии/распаковке файла.